# How to make sure selenium does not close the browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I was working on something that requires me to keep the browser open until unless it is closed by the user, however, the browser automatically closes after finishing its tasks, is there any way to prevent this?

```
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to stay open, you have to use the 'detach' option

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def main():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

This should do it

Comment: @AamodVarma Glad I could help! Make sure to mark this as solved for future visitors!