# URL is auto closed when I want it to remain open - using selenium web driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python `3.10.10` and Selenium `4.14.0` I tried this code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

The website is auto-closed. What can I do?

I want the website to remain open. I don't need it to be closed.

Comment: the website opens and immediately  closes because there are no other lines of code. ill link a question with an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make sure selenium does not close the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425419/how-to-make-sure-selenium-does-not-close-the-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window made by python selenium disappears immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400488/window-made-by-python-selenium-disappears-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Try with Chrome options

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Comment: I got the same issue and the website is auto closed

Comment: Have you tried the Chrome options I provided?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me with Eclypse, but not with VScode